# Mexican wave in Swift string

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I need to print a String as if a [Mexican Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_(audience)) is passing through each character in the String:

```
wave("hello") -> ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]
```

For current moment I'm stopped at:

```
var str = "hel lo"
var arr = [String]()
str = str.lowercased()
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

for i in str {
    arr.append (str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(i)", with: i.uppercased()))
}
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply map your string indices and replace its character at each iteration:

---

```
let string = "hello"
let result = string.indices.map {
    string.replacingCharacters(in: $0...$0, with: string[$0...$0].uppercased()) 
}

print(result)
```

---

This will print:

> ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]

Comment: In that case I see "error: value of type 'String' has no member 'replacingCharacters'"

Comment: What is your Xcode/Swift version?

Comment: I'm checked with 12.4, working well! thanks a lot it's perfect solution

Comment: You are welcome. Do you know how to mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

After many iterations and doc reviews, also find this solution:

```
func wave(_ y: String) -> [String] {
    if y.count == 0 {
        return [String]()
    }
    var wave = [String]()
    for i in y.indices {
        if !y[i].isWhitespace{
            wave.append(y[..<i] + y[i].uppercased() + y[y.index(after: i)...])
        }
    }
    return wave
}
```